# Import C4D models' textures to Blender 3.6 (C4D Release 16)

Tags: shaders, import

I'm trying to export a C4D model with C4D 'textures' that would appear as Blender image shading. Straight RGB colours do import perfectly well, but none of the images used for shading surfaces (Apparently C4D Release 16 had the capability to achieve this?). So C4D models import without image shading, only straight RGB coloured. Grateful for any advice.